# Save django models to XML

Tags: python, xml, django

I have this django view code that saves my django model to xml file.

```
def my_serialize(request):
    from django.core import serializers
    data = serializers.serialize("xml", LogChanges.objects.all())
    from django.core.files import File
    f = open('tickets.xml', 'w')
    myfile = File(f)
    myfile.write(data)
    myfile.close()
    return HttpResponse("All done!")
```

Then I get the output this way:

```
<django-objects version="1.0">
    <object pk="1" model="ticket.logchanges">
        <field type="CharField" name="prevRemarks">action taken</field>
        <field type="IntegerField" name="idTicket">1</field>
        <field type="DateTimeField" name="dateChanged">2015-09-05</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="status">Open</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="userID">admin</field>
    </object>
</django-objects
```

Is there a way that I can save this in a simpler form of xml, without using a library, or do I really have to use a library? Like:

```
<rowset> 
    <row>
        <prevRemarks> action taken </prevRemarks>
        <idTicket>1</idTicket>
        ...etc...
    </row>
</rowset>
```

Comment: XML is nice but wouldn't you rather use the more versatile and compact JSON ?

Comment: @e4c5 I want to use it to load some data so I will not access the database every time I want those pieces of info. Can you elaborate how can I use JSON here?

Comment: Sounds like what you are really looking for is caching. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/

Comment: @e4c5 JSON is more compact, but it is definitely not more versatile.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [XML renderer plugin for Django Rest Framework](http://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-xml/) might suit your preferences a bit better.

Sample output for User model:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <list-item>
        <id>1</id>
        <username>jpadilla</username>
        <email>jpadilla@example.com</email>
        <is_staff>True</is_staff>
    </list-item>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into this. But isn't there any other way that does not involve using a library?

Comment: @predator Sure. You can use the Django template system to output custom XML just as easily as you already use it to output custom HTML. My personal preference would be to use the library but I see how if you aren't using `django-rest-framework` it's a bit of an odd dependency to add to solve the problem.